# Did Sagara originally desire 60,000 daughters ergo threatening Indra?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, indra, vishnu-purana

What's the scriptural basis behind the lore of Indra feeling threatened by Sagara's desire to beget 60,000 daughters?

Comment: I'm really curious as to where did you read about this "daughter-story" though?! Any blog or article something?!

Comment: @Vivikta I came across this video https://youtu.be/HoDtuPWZLc8 but couldn't find any scriptural backing. Hence the doubt

Comment: Oh Okay! Seems like folklore, not canonical. Multiple accounts exist due to the "Kalpa-bheda". However, never heard of this version. @RishitaGhosh